# How to do something when the user leaves the current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, android-button

How can I run some code when the user presses the back button?

Answer (score 3):

As stated You can call your method from onPause()

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
}
```

But there are case scenarios when two different layouts are used.In this case onPause() will also be called on orientation change. So you can modify your code like this

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
  super.onPause()
  if(isFinishing())
  {
    //Do what you wan tot do here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override the following method in your code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            /* Type here what u wanted to do on pressing the back button*/
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we move from one activity to another the onPause method is called.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    //code
}
```

Use this function to do some action